# Gradient descent derivation in Eigenspace

Tags: gradient-descent, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to decode article on https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/
 I was able to follow everything until the part with a change of basis x$^k=Q^T(w^k−w^⋆)$ to eigenspace... I conceptually understand what it means, however, I don't fully understand how we derived $x^k$ variable and what this variable represents, this part is quite confusing to me. 
On one hand, we have symmetric Q matrix (why is it transposed?) and also $(w^k-w^*)$ which should represent how far is $w^k$ from optimal $w^*$.
Unfortunately, I cannot put it together, and I am unable to derive this from anything mentioned before... Can you explain a little bit more about the problem? Is it just simple translation of some of the previous formulas to the Q basis (which I somehow missed) or something totally different?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may be a duplicate, but in the event it isn't...

Since $A$ is a symmetric and invertible, then the eigenvectors of $A$ form an orthonormal basis.  This has the consequence of meaning $Q^{-1} = Q^T$.  Thus, $Q^T$ is a linear function mapping elements of the $w$ space to $x$ space.  This explains why $Q^T$ appears in the defeinition of $x_k$.

I think that addresses your first problem.  Please limit posts to one question.  If this does not answer your question, please make an edit to be more precise.

Comment: Hi Demetri, Thank you for the answer, so if I understand correctly. It means that error $w^k-w^∗$ is, after transformation equal to $Qx^k$, $Q$ being a matrix containing eigenvectors translating error to eigenspace where it is represented by $x$. Is that correct?

Comment: @GrumpyC Yes, I believe so.